# Umbraco limit number of child nodes under a parent

Tags: umbraco

Is there a way to limit the number of children that can be created under a parent node in Umbraco, ideally I would like to only allow one?

I am not sure if this can be done either via the CMS or set via code in a config file.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, there's no such functionality built into Umbraco, nor are there options to configure it directly.

Longer answer: you could implement a bit of code that hooks into the Saving event (https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Events/ContentService-Events#events). There you could check the number of siblings (or rather if there are siblings at all) of any node that hasn't been saved previously - and cancel further saving if any siblings already exist.

Sounds a bit funny to need that, though. What is the scenario?

Comment: It might be that I have just set the document type wrong, the idea is to have a page and some pages have one child page with its own URL. Is there a better way?

Comment: Well, I'm just wondering when and why that specific functionality is needed, really. It can be that there are certain requirements to your content structure, but generally I just find it odd and am wondering whether your content structure could be different so you don't need this restriction :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is [a valid scenario](https://www.dot-see.com/en/blog/noderestrict-stop-users-from-adding-more-nodes-than-needed/) and depending on your Umbraco version, you can use a package, namely [NodeRetrict](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/backoffice-extensions/noderestrict/), to restrict the number of nodes that could be created under a parent node.

Please be aware that this package currently supports some Umbraco v7 versions, but not Umbraco v8 and v9 versions.

If you want to check this package to create your own solution or contribute to this package, please take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/sotirisf/Umbraco-NodeRestrict/).